# Default Area Controller with Actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have a Area called `Admin` where I have a `HomeController`.
I would like to be able to go to `/Admin/Login` and use the `Login` action in `HomeController` so I would be able to add a `Register` action as well for `/Admin/Register`.

I've managed to change the default route to `HomeController` but now I'm stuck..

```
context.MapRoute(
  "Admin_default",
  "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_Login",
    "Admin/Login/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_Register",
    "Admin/Register/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Register", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```